# Is cellular wifi hotspotting same as having 2 devices on the same wifi?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, google-chrome, android, hotspot

If I connect my laptop to my phone's cell network through hotspot, are they considered on the same network? I'm trying to cast video from my phone to my laptop but they need to be on the same network. I don't have wifi where I am so I'm using my phone but i'm not entirely sure if that will work.

Comment: "If I connect my laptop to my phones cell network through hotspot, are they considered on the same network?" - Is your laptop connected to your cellular service, it is connected to your cell phone, all traffic is routed through the phone.  You would need to connect your phone to the same WiFi access point to accomplish what you describe.

Comment: When I turn on my wifi and hotspot is already enabled, it disables the hotspotting.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any other behavior. I am pretty sure that Android/iOS, both use the WiFi adapter, to create the hotspot functionality. The answer to your question by the way, incase it wasn't clear, is the phone and any client devices connected to your phone will not be connected to the same network.  Which is the reason I indicated that, "You would need to connect your phone to the same WiFi access point to accomplish what you describe.", in my original comment.  I personally don't find short answer which response in the negative to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes. The scenario is that you are using are are using two network adapters where one has access to internet (through cellular ISP) and the other creates an ad-hoc wireless access point that shares the data *i.e the traffic is being through the device to other secondary devices.*

In this way you can still access local (intranet) resources as well as external (internet) through your ISP because you have two **gateways**:

- `192.168.43.xx`
- `10.xx.xx.xx`

So  its like you are connected to same wi-fi network.

---

However this configuration is **not supported** for casting.

Instead, its possible and much easier if you have two devices (e.g 2nd smartphone, tablet or PC):

- Device 1 (either a mobile phone, or separate mobile hotspot) to act as your Wi-Fi hotspot.
- Device 2 (with supported operating system) tethered to Device 1, and to cast your content.

You can get more details by following this discussion: [Casting from mobile hotspot phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175640/209414)

*Note: You may need to update your Google Play Services to get the best experience*

Comment: @Batman did you resolve the issue?